# Change color of Switch while turning OFF react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using react native switch component and I want to change the color of switch when I turn it OFF.

I can add `onTintColor` property to change the color when it is turned on.

Is there any way to change the color while turning it OFF?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

onTintColor has been deprecated try the following.

```
  <Switch 
      trackColor={{true: 'red', false: 'grey'}}
      onValueChange={this.toggleSwitch}
      value={true}/>
```

this works

Comment: On Android (react-native 0.61.5), it will give a green thumb-circle (which is bad)

Answer (score 27):

I've design switch with platform specific, also used border based on On Off status.

```
<Switch
trackColor={{ true: '#7ab8e1', false: Platform.OS=='android'?'#d3d3d3':'#fbfbfb'  }}
thumbColor={[Platform.OS=='ios'?'#FFFFFF':(item.status ?'#7ab8e1':'#ffffff')]}
ios_backgroundColor="#fbfbfb"
style={[item.status ?inline_styles.switchEnableBorder:inline_styles.switchDisableBorder]}
value={item.status}
onValueChange={() =>this.change_status(index)            }
/>
```

Inline border Style

```
const inline_styles = StyleSheet.create({
switchEnableBorder: {
borderColor: '#6fa6d3',
borderWidth: 1},

switchDisableBorder: {
borderColor: '#f2f2f2',
borderWidth: 1,  },});
```

Android OutPut :[image: Android]   iOS Output : [image: iOS]

Comment: It's wild that `Switch` allows independent on/off colors for the `trackColor`, but not for the `thumbColor`, even though the thumb will have two different colors for on/off if you do not specify a custom color.

Answer (score 9):

Just add:

```
style={{backgroundColor: '#FF0000', borderRadius: 17}}
```

To the Switch

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT:** This is a fairly old and invalid answer now. Please refer to the accepted one.

<s>React native has `ColorSwitchExample` in their docs. You can refer the same [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/switch.html#examples). Good luck!</s>

<s>class ColorSwitchExample extends React.Component {
      state = {
        colorTrueSwitchIsOn: true,
        colorFalseSwitchIsOn: false,
      };
    
      render() {
        return (
          
             this.setState({colorFalseSwitchIsOn: value})}
              onTintColor="#00ff00"
              style={{marginBottom: 10}}
              thumbTintColor="#0000ff"
              tintColor="#ff0000"
              value={this.state.colorFalseSwitchIsOn} />
             this.setState({colorTrueSwitchIsOn: value})}
              onTintColor="#00ff00"
              thumbTintColor="#0000ff"
              tintColor="#ff0000"
              value={this.state.colorTrueSwitchIsOn} />
          
        );
      }
    }</s>

Comment: @Ankush Rishi I don't think you can change the appearance of the switch when it is off but you change the strip color with tintColor and change circle color with thumbTintColor.

Comment: @RajeevUpadhyay Did you run the example on their page? I can see the switch changing color after turning it off! Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Mihir I want to change the background color, thumbTintColor will change the color of the slider only and tintColor will change the border color. Just like onTintColor is what I want when the switch is in Off mode

Answer (score 5):

For anyone coming from Google:
Specifically for iOS, you'll need to use the `ios_backgroundColor` property:

```
<Switch ios_backgroundColor="red" trackColor={{ true: 'blue', false: 'red' }} />
```

References:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/switch.html#trackcolor

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/switch#ios-backgroundcolor

Answer (score 2):

You can use the example provided by Mihir, and that should work for iOS. If you want something that uses Material Design and that works on both Android and iOS (as of this writing, React-Native does not allow recoloring of Android switches), you can try this package:

https://github.com/recr0ns/react-native-material-switch

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
<Switch
trackColor={{true: '#3bde50', false: '#f5f6fc'}}
thumbColor='#FFF'
onValueChange={() => this.toggleSwitch(item, index)}
value={this.state.isActive}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Switch
   ios_backgroundColor={Colors.secondaryTextColor}
   thumbColor={[Platform.OS=='ios'?'white': 'white']}
   trackColor={{ true: Colors.primaryColor, false: Colors.secondaryTextColor }}
   style={{ transform: [{ scaleX: .7 }, { scaleY: .7 }] }}
   value={this.state.toggleChatSwitch}
   onValueChange={() => this.onChatSwitchPressed()}
                                            />
```

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem. See [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: when turning off in trackColor object false property trigger and color is chaged

Comment: Ha thanks, the explanation should go into your answer - just edit it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/switch) to change thumb color dynamically too:

```
<Switch
    trackColor={{ false: "#767577", true: "#81b0ff" }}
    thumbColor={isEnabled ? "#f5dd4b" : "#f4f3f4"}
    ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
    onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
    value={isEnabled}
/>
```

Comment: ios_backgroundColor works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
style={{backgroundColor: selectedLanguage == "en" ? color.Blue : color.Gray,borderRadius:15}}
```